# how to express a number only in exponential form of product of 3 and 7 or say any two numbers?

Tags: exponential-function

please guide me how to expand a number in the form of $3^x 7^y$
example:

$1 = 3^0 7^0$

$21 = 3^1  7^1$

i have tried by finding numbers which can be expressed in form of any one such as for only $3^x$ but cant find in the product form

Comment: Dived the nuber by $3$ until you cannot, then divide what you're left with by $7$ until you cannot anymore. If you're left with only $1$, then that number is not the product of a power of $7$ and a power of $3$.

Answer (score 1):

You need to factorise the number into prime dividers. Then, look for the number of 3's and the number of 7's and that are the exponents of 
  
    3
    x
  
  
    7
    y